# SQL Trigger that runs ONLY at Publisher

Tags: sql-server, triggers, replication, merge-replication, occasionallyconnected

I have an in house app that has both a Web Interface and a Desktop Interface(*is an OCA using Merge Replication*).  We are still using SQL 2005 and have many 'Archive' tables set up.  These are filled by Triggers on there relating `Table`.  `tblPersonArchive` for `tblPerson`, etc.  To keep the Replication Sets as small as possible I would like to exclude ALL of the Archive tables from replicating.

This shouldn't be an issue from a Business standpoint as that data is never accessed directly by the user's.  There is literally no need for it to exist on the Desktop app that is using replication.

What I am trying to figure out, then, is how I accomplish that.  My "guess" is that I set the `Publication Properties --> Article Properties --> Copy User Triggers = FALSE`  and then exclude the Archive Tables from the Replication Set.  Theoretically the Triggers will still fire, and thus still maintain, the Archive tables through the Web App and on Replication.

Unfortunately, this is only a guess at this point and I was hoping for a little reassurance before plowing in.

Answer (score 1):

Could you not accomplish Publisher only triggers by using the NOT FOR REPLICATION clause in the trigger creation?